# What is the best way to store multiple items in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

There is no problem with one element. I need to make at least 10 buttons, and so that they do not depend on each other. That is, some buttons were with hidden text, and others with open text.

What is the best way to do this so that the code does not look like a freak?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#myid { display: none; }
</style>

<button onclick="onclickmyid()">Open</button><br><br><span id="myid">Hidden text</span>

<script>
var myid = document.getElementById('myid');
function onclickmyid() {
  myid.style.display = (myid.style.display == 'block') ? '' : 'block';
  localStorage.setItem('conceal', myid.style.display); 
}
if(localStorage.getItem('conceal') == 'block') { 
  document.getElementById('myid').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try and rephrase your question

Answer (score 1):

Put all the persistent data you need into an array or an object, then serialize that (single) array or object into a single Local Storage key. Something along the lines of

```
const config = localStorage.config
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.config)
  : defaultConfig; // define defaultConfig earlier
cons saveConfig = () => localStorage.config = JSON.stringify(config);

// then, to save to the config when a change is made:
function onclickmyid() {
  const newShow = myid.style.display === '';
  config.myid = newShow;
  updateUI();
  saveConfig();
}

// and retrieve values on pageload:
const updateUI = () => {
  myid.style.display = config.myid ? 'block' : '';
  // etc for other elements
};
updateUI();
```

I'd also highly, highly recommend avoiding inline handlers, they're pretty universally considered to be quite terrible practice nowadays - attach listeners properly using JavaScript's [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead whenever possible.

For additional buttons, just add more properties to the `config` object, and toggle and access them in the click handlers.

Comment: Thank you for the link to addEventListener, there is a very detailed description. But your example is still difficult for me. Can you show a minimal example for two buttons?

Comment: For additional buttons, just add more properties to the `config` object, and toggle and access them in the click handlers.